# Do not interpret space as delimiter in semicolon separated list

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, delimiter

I have the following code:

```
set "x=c:\aa;c:\bb;c:\c c"

for %%g in (%x%) do (
    echo %%g
)
```

It outputs:

```
c:\aa
c:\bb
c:\c
c
```

It interprets the space as delimiter. But I don't want this. Only the semicolon should be a valid separator. Thee output should be:

```
c:\aa
c:\bb
c:\c c
```

It should work for any number of entries. I found solutions, but they where quite complicated. I'm looking for a simple solution, if there's any. The list can have another format if needed.

Comment: Use string substitution to double quote all semicolon separated elements => `for %%g in ("%x:;=";"%") do echo %%~g`

Comment: It works. If I understood it correctly, this produces "c:\aa""c:\bb""c:\c c". I really have a hard time to undersand the quoting rules of batch scripts. Do you know a good source for this topic?

Comment: no, it produces ` "c:\aa";"c:\bb";"c:\c c"` - three quoted strings delimited by `;`. Quoting is required, when a string contains a space (but it's much easier to quote all of them instead of checking if there is a space and only quote if yes)

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate. The linked question already contains the answer.

Comment: `%x%`is enclosed in outer double quotes and the semicolons themselves are replaced with `";"`. On output use the tilde `~` to strip the double quotes. In general cmd supports only double quotes to *hide* content (poisenous chars like `<>|&`) from being interpreted directly, aside from escaping with a `^`, or in case of the percent sign, doubling it.

Comment: It looks likes quotes can be nested. Is this always the case?

Comment: there is no nesting. It's `"String1" ; "String2" ; "String3"` (inserted spaces for readability).

Comment: @Stephen I'm talking about "%x:;=";"%"

Comment: That might look like nesting, but in fact isn't. The parser first evaluates the variable, replacing `;` with `";"` (that's not a quoted `;`, but a quote plus a `;` plus another quote) and only then adds the quotes at the beginning and the end (that's technically still no quoting). After that, the `for` takes that construct and interprets it as quoted strings. If you want to know more, get yourself a big cup of coffee and some time to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)